# JavaFX VBox.getHeight() returns wrong value

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a program that converts a .xml file, containing information regarding a UML diagram, to an actual UML diagram. To draw arrows, I need to get the height of the VBoxes I'm using (they are children of an AnchorPane). I did the following thing:

```
pane.applyCss();
pane.layout();
VBox.getHeight();
```

But the getHeight() value returns the wrong value. It should be something around 40 but I get 32.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Hqve you taken the insets of the node in consideration? (Border and shadow etc.?)

Comment: Not really. Is there a way to get the y coördinate of the bottom of a VBox using insets?

Answer (score 0):

It might help to get this value relative to its parent pane:

```
double requestedHeight = yourVBox.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
```

Comment: Tried this aswell, also gives the same wrong value. The issue seems to be that it 'forgets' the height of the last label/text I added to my VBox when calculating the height.